# How to make Cursor Position track SelectionState in DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, draftjs

I'm noticing that when I programmatically update `SelectionState` using `EditorState.forceSelection(...)`, cursor/caret selection in the text editor does not change on rerender. Has anyone run into this issue? Is there a programmatic way accessing and changing this "true" selection information?